# Check every 3 rows to see if a text value is in it?

Tags: excel

I have column A and every 3 rows I want to check to see if the value "Fail" exists in there.

I have this, but I need to figure out the function to set the range to every 3 rows to check for the value:

`=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(A2:A4,"Fail")),"Fail","Pass")`

the `A2:A4` is the 3 row range that I need to check every segment (e.g. A5:A7, A8:A10). If any one of the 3 cells in that range has the word "Fail" then I need to label all three cells in the formula column "Fail"

any ideas?

Comment: I assume you want to be able to drag it down and each row it is dragged down would move to the next three?  Or do you want to drag it down and only put out the answer if it happens to be the third row other wise return an empty string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this with `COUNTIFS`, `INDEX`, `ROW`, and `MOD`:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(INDEX(A:A,ROW()-MOD(ROW()+1,3)):INDEX(A:A,ROW()+2-MOD(ROW()+1,3)),"Fail"),"Fail","Pass")
```

[image]